# Capybara: How to force it to use JavaScript driver on all tests?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I want to show my boss how testing makes our lives easier and save a lot of money in the long run.

For this, I'd like to show him all my Cucumber tests with active JavaScript driver, so all tests are run in the browser, not only the ones marked with @javascript/@selenium.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this somewhere sensible like your env.rb:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```